# Firebase Cloud Messaging Push Notificartions don't arrive on iOS anymore

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS. I have implemented Firebase into the app like stated in the docs and a Firebase instance id is generated. However, if I try to send a push notification (for example using http://pushtry.com/), nothing happened. The thing is, it *did* work, and I don't remember changing anything to do with notifications.

Because I couldn't find anything, I even tried deleting the whole project and doing everything again from scratch (by copying the code). Then it worked again, but now (an hour later) again, it again doesn't work.

If I send a FCM from pushtry or from the Firebase Console, it says the message is delivered, but nothing happens! (Push notifications are enabled in the iOS Settings. It did work)

I really don't know what to do. Does anybody know about anything I could do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after two whole days of utmost frustration, I figured it out.
The problem was the line `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` set to `NO` in the `info.plist` file.

After I removed the line, the problem was gone!

I am so relieved right now

Comment: This is a weird parameter. I've been looking for the problem 'Unable to fetch APNS token' for 2 days now and adding 'FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = false' to the info.plist solved it for me. Quite your opposite. I'm running tests on an iPad Pro (OS v10). Which version is your device?

Comment: iPad Pro 9.7, iOS 10.3.3

Comment: The 'Unable to fetch APNS token' message is a red herring. Firebase does fetch the APNS token in the end. I also ended up setting the proxy parameter to true (YES).

Answer (score 0):

set parameter `content_available` to `true`

Comment: I did that. As I said, even the messages sent from the official Firebase Console don't arrive anymore on the device even though it says "sent" on the site.

Comment: use your own back end server to handle notifications to make sure it works

Comment: Most of the time messages do arrive on iOS but from time to time we have to delete the Token in order to regain communication.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had migrated my Apple account and forgot to configure both my Apple and Firebase account correctly.

**Apple side**

1. Make sure that "Push Notification" is enabled for that app id.
2. Make sure that you had created "Apple Push Notification service" certificate and attached to the Apple Id.
3. Create an Authorization Key that will be later updated load Firebase so it can communicate with Apple servers in your behalf. ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns))

**Firebase side**

1. Make sure your iOS apple bundle is set correctly in your Firebase project
2. Upload the Authorization key you created before in Apple - Step 3 above. ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key))
3. Follow all the steps to have the iOS app integrated with Firebase SDK

That is it.